# Trying to activate a checkbox from a controller that lives in another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to activate a checkbox from a controller that lives in another controller.  For example, I have a card named `information technology` under a separate controller and when I click this I want it to route to another page that has a checkbox for `information technology` from another controller and I want it checked as it renders the page.

The application architecture is very lengthy so I wont include any code base here.  But I would like to know an approach I can take.

This is the controller where I want the logic to live and to mark a text box as checked (which lives on another controller).

```js
angular
  .controller("mycontroller", mycontroller);
  mycontroller.$inject = [
        "$scope"
    ];

    // getting the getData() data
        $scope.getData = function (data, type) {
            console.log("whats this data about in getData(data) ", data)
            $scope.query = data.name;
            if (data.checked == undefined) {
                data.checked = true;
            }
        }
```

Below: Is the controller where the checkbox controller lives

```js
angular
    .controller('supplierIntelligenceCtrl', function ($scope, $q, FetchData, dataStore, SharedService,
        $document, $window, $state, $rootScope, $timeout, DataCache,
        $filter, $interval, $localStorage, $http) {

                $scope.getData = function (data, type) {
            console.log("whats this data about in getData(data) ", data)
            $scope.query = data.name;
            if (data.checked == undefined) {
                data.checked = true;
            }


        }

        $scope.apply = function (type) {
            $scope.select = false;
            $scope.bigres = 0;
            $scope.mobFil = 3;
            $scope.applyFilter(type);
        }

        $scope.disableApply = false;
        $scope.disableApply2 = false;

        $scope.applyFilter = function (type) {
            console.log("this is type ", type)
            if (type == 'industries') {
                $scope.filters.industries = $scope.industries.filter(function (e) {
                    console.log("this is e ", e.checked)
                    return e.checked;
                }).map(function (f) {
                    console.log(" this is f >>>> ",
                        f)
                    return f.id
                })

                $scope.filters.countries = [];
                if ($scope.countries != undefined) {
                    $scope.countries = $scope.countries.map(function (e) {
                        e.checked = false;
                        return e;
                    })
                }
                $scope.filters.cities = [];
                if ($scope.cities != undefined) {
                    $scope.cities = $scope.cities.map(function (e) {
                        e.checked = false;
                        return e;
                    })
                }
                $scope.start = 0;
                if ($scope.filters.industries.length > 0) {
                    $scope.callBackend();
                    $scope.disableApply2 = true;
                    FetchData.fetchDNBCountriesByIndustries('industries=' + $scope.filters.industries + '&size=').then(function (res) {
                        $scope.disableApply2 = false;
                        $scope.countries = res.data;
                        $scope.countriesPage += 10
                    }, function () {
                        $scope.disableApply2 = false;
                    });
                } else {
                    $scope.callBackend();
                }
            }
            if (type == 'countries') {

                $scope.filters.countries = $scope.countries.filter(function (e) {
                    return e.checked;
                }).map(function (f) {
                    return f.id;
                })
                $scope.filters.cities = [];
                if ($scope.cities != undefined) {
                    $scope.cities = $scope.cities.map(function (e) {
                        e.checked = false;
                        return e;
                    })
                }
                $scope.start = 0;
                if ($scope.filters.countries.length > 0) {
                    $scope.callBackend();
                    $scope.disableApply2 = true;
                    FetchData.fetchDNBCitiesByIndustriesAndCountries('industries=' + $scope.filters.industries + '&countries=' + $scope.filters.countries + '&size=').then(function (res) {
                        $scope.disableApply2 = false;
                        $scope.cities = res.data;
                    }, function () {
                        $scope.disableApply2 = false;
                    })
                } else {
                    $scope.callBackend();
                }
            }
            if (type == 'cities') {
                $scope.filters.cities = $scope.cities.filter(function (e) {
                    return e.checked;
                }).map(function (f) {
                    return f.id
                })
                $scope.start = 0;
                $scope.callBackend();
            }


            if (type == 'classifications') {
                $scope.filters.classifications = $scope.classifications.filter(function (e) {
                    return e.checked;
                }).map(function (f) {
                    return f.statusCode;
                })
                $scope.start = 0;
                $scope.callBackend();
            }
        }

        }
```

Here is the HTML where the checkbox lives:

```html
<div ng-repeat="data in industries  ">                                 
   <input id="{{data.id}}in" type="checkbox" aria-invalid="false"
          ng-model="data.checked"
          ng-change="getData(data,'industry')">
  <label for="{{data.id}}in">{{data.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Maybe Im missing the point here and perhaps am overlooking something.  Im new to angularjs and need to implement this capability to route a button/card to another page that checks a checkbox filter.

Please - any advise would be great . :)

Comment: Typically a service is used when you want to share data between controllers. This works because in AngularJS a service is a singleton so once the initial instance has been created it is shared everywhere else in your app that you access it. This makes it very easy to share data throughout your app no matter how many controllers you have nor what order they are accessed.

Comment: Like the proverbial needle in the haystack, you’ve made it hard for people to find the error in your code. Your real problem lies only in a few instructions, and most of the code posted is completely irrelevant to the resolution of your issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `ng-repeat` with the checkboxes looks OK and the `$scope.getData` function that the `ng-change` directive invokes looks OK.

Comment: @Lex - I like your suggestion.  Could you give me an example of this approach? PLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of controllers sharing an array via a shared service injected by the dependency injector. Check the checkbox in one controller and it shows in the other.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
  .factory('dataService', [function () {
    return {
      data: [
        { prop: '1', checked: false },
        { prop: '2', checked: false },
        { prop: '3', checked: false },
        { prop: '4', checked: false }
      ]
    };
  }]);

angular.module('app')
  .controller('controller1', ['dataService', function (dataService) {
    this.data = dataService.data;
  }]);

angular.module('app')
  .controller('controller2', ['dataService', function (dataService) {
    this.data = dataService.data;
  }]);
  
angular.module('app')
  .controller('controller3', ['dataService', function (dataService) {
    this.toggleAll = () => {
      dataService.data.forEach(item => item.checked = !item.checked)
    };
  }]);
```

```css
[ng-controller] { display: inline-block; margin-right: 30px; vertical-align: top; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="controller1 as ctrl">
    <strong>Controller 1</strong>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.data">
      <label>Item {{item.prop}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div ng-controller="controller2 as ctrl">
    <strong>Controller 2</strong>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.data">
      <label>Item {{item.prop}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div ng-controller="controller3 as ctrl">
    <strong>Controller 3</strong>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="ctrl.toggleAll()">Toggle all</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put industries as a property on a shared service that you inject into both of the controllers by the dependency injector. Then one controller can bind it to it's view and the other one can change the checked properties on them.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Brand.. Could you give me simple example of this approach.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about redirection and then checking a check box, you can try either of below options

1. Send selection 'information technology' in query string to redirected page and check the check box
2. If you own a back end server then put the value in cookie and read it in your angular js app

Hope this helps.