# $scope.feeds getting updated but the view won't update the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

$scope.feeds is getting updated within the controller. But the view won't update the variable. The feeds variable is in a ng-repeat.

Angular Code:

```
$scope.openfeeds = function(category){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url:  '/category/feeds/'+category.id
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         $scope.feeds = response.data;
         console.log($scope.feeds);
    });
};
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="c-Subscribe">
        <div class="c-Subscribe_feeds" ng-repeat="feed in feeds" ng-controller="LinkController">
            @{{feed}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Whereas, there is another variable called categories which right above it. It is getting updated with the same way I am doing it to update the feeds.

```
<div class="c-modal_content">
        <div class="c-categoryTile_blocks">
            <div class="c-categoryTile" ng-repeat="category in categories">
                <div class="c-categoryTile_background" style="background-image: url('/images/biker-circuit-competition-63249.jpg');">
                    <a href="" ng-controller="LinkController" ng-click="openfeeds(category)">@{{ category.category }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Each instance of a controller is a `new` instance and each has it's own scope and knows nothing about other instances. Doesn't make a lot of sense adding `ng-controller` to your links and creating a new controller instance for each one

Comment: Right so I removed the instances. And copied all the functions in one controller Category. It worked. But is there any way that i can make a global variable for each controller?

Comment: Can use an angular service to share data and methods across various parts of the app

Comment: Right Ill look into it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the same answer that I gave to this question [How to preserve scope data when changing states with ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508281/how-to-preserve-scope-data-when-changing-states-with-ui-router/54508399#54508399)

You need to under stand how prototypal inheritance works. When a parent puts a property value on the scope with

```
$scope.value = 'something';
```

In a child component if you access $scope.value the inheritance chain will find $scope.value.

If the child sets

```
$scope.otherValue = 'something';
```

If follows the inheritance chain, doesn't find a value of otherValue and creates a property on the child scope, not the inherited prototype so the parent component and any other children of the parent do not see it.

You can use what is called the dot rule of prototypal inheritance. If the parent creates an object on the scope called something like data

```
$scope.data = { value: 'something' };
```

Now if the child puts a property on the data object

```
$scope.data.otherValue = 'something';
```

It looks for the data object, finds it in the inheritence chain and because you are adding a property to an instance of an object it is visible to the parent and any children of the parent.

```js
let parent = {
  value: 'some value',
  data: { value: 'some value' }
};

let child = Object.create(parent);

console.log(child.value); // Finds value on the prototype chain

child.newValue = 'new value'; // Does not affect the parent

console.log(parent.newValue);

child.data.newValue = 'new value'; // newValue is visible to the parent

console.log(parent.data.newValue);
```

Short answer is to just never inject $scope and use controllerAs syntax.

To share data between controllers you use a service that is injected to both controllers. You have the spots collection on the service and use a route param to identify which spot the other controller should use or have a place on the service called currentSpot set by the other controller.

Services are a singleton object that you create at the module level and then all controllers that ask for them in their dependency list get the same instance. They are the preferred way to share data between controllers, $scope hierarchies are bound to lead to confusion as the prototypal inheritance nature of them can be confusing. A child $scope is prototypally inherited from it's parent, this seems like you should be sharing data but when a child controller sets a property it is not visible to the parent.

You are learning an outdated way of Angular programming. Injecting $scope is no longer a recommended way. Look at using components. Components are a wrapper for a controller with an isolated scope and using contollerAs syntax. Isolated scopes make it much cleaner to know where data comes from.

Take a look at my answer on this question

[Trying to activate a checkbox from a controller that lives in another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994536/trying-to-activate-a-checkbox-from-a-controller-that-lives-in-another-controller/51997666#51997666)