# AngularJS: keep state of input checked after change view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

The site I am working on displays news in one of two ways: list or grid view.

The default mode is list. The user can change the mode through options located at the top:

[image]

The options are in a div and a label:

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="view-card-mode" data-intro="{{uikey.chTipoVista}}" data-position="bottom">
  <label class="btn btn-default grid-view" title="{{uikey.VistaGrilla}}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="grid-view" autocomplete="off" checked>
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default list-view active" title="{{uikey.VistaLista}}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="list-view" autocomplete="off">
    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

But in the controller of this page there is no reference to these controls.
The change in the view is made through jquery:

```js
// List/Grid View
$('#view-card-mode .list-view').off('click');
$('#view-card-mode .list-view').on('click', function() {
  $('.card-container').addClass('card-list');
  $('.card-container').removeClass('card-grid');
  $('.actions-list').show();
  $('.actions-grid').hide();
});

$('#view-card-mode .grid-view').off('click');
$('#view-card-mode .grid-view').on('click', function() {
  $('.card-container').removeClass('card-list');
  $('.card-container').addClass('card-grid');
  $('.actions-list').hide();
  $('.actions-grid').show();
});
```

So, when I click on "grid view icon", the function add a class "grid" on the following div(by default is list view):

```html
<div class="card-container card-list" id="menucontext">
```

The problem is If I select "grid view", when i change the state of the page (for example, i visit a news and then go back), the selection is gone, always return to list view (the default)

Is there any way I can keep the view selected via angularjs or jquery? I have little experience with angularjs and I am still trying to undertand the logic behind data binding.

I searched other similar questions but nothing worked. I have even tried to convert the jquery function into angular but I am not sure how to bind then into the html:

Controller First try:

```js
$scope.view = 'card-container card-list';
$scope.viewTypeSelected = "list";

$scope.changeView = function() {
  if ($scope.viewTypeSelected === "list") {
    $scope.view = 'card-container card-grid';
  } else {
    $scope.view = 'card-container card-list';
  }
}
```

Controller Second try:

```js
$scope.viewTypesCtrl = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.views = ["card-grid", "card-list"];
  self.changeView = changeView;

  function changeView(view) {
    self.viewSelected = view;
  }
}
```

I need to clarify that the site works normally, there are no problems. I just have to add this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is using jQuery with Angular and this is exactly why it is frowned upon. Why would you use Angular and not do things through template binding? This whole approached needs a major refactoring. Have a look at this answer I did a while ago, might help you get on the right path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994536/trying-to-activate-a-checkbox-from-a-controller-that-lives-in-another-controller